# Typescript generic interface with dynamic keys

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Hey there is the following somehow possible in TS?

#### warning: extreme pseudocode incoming!

```
interface MyInterface<T> {
    ${T}_function: (a: number): void;
    ${T}_prop: number;
}

MyClass implements MyInterface<'Example'> {
    // TSLINT-GOD says:
    // You need to implement: 
    // -> Example_prop of type number and
    // -> Example_function with signature (a: number): void;
}
```

if possible a use case would look like:

```
MyClass implements MyInterface<'cat'>, MyInterface<'dog'> {
   I know I have to implement 4 function with specific name.
}
```

Comment: Ok here's where this is problematic. you need to have T always be a single string. Not only that it has to be a specific single string. For example `MyInterface<string>` would not be allowed. `MyInterface<'example1'|'example2'>` would also not be allowed. This is so insanely specific it really screams [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me

Comment: Im happy to have a workaround. This preudocode just explains what im after.

Comment: Until [this feature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754) is implemented in TypeScript I don't think that's possible.